# Are these the two constraints in this system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Consider a mass $m$ restricted to moving along a helix of fixed radius $b$ placed along the $z$ axis. Using cylindrical coordinates, also consider $z=a\varphi$.

To me it seems pretty clear that the system has two constraints: one caused by the fixed radius and one caused by $z=a\varphi$. Is that correct?

Comment: My apologies if you consider  this comment pedantic, but if you want to consider ALL possible constraints, should you also allow for the environment in which the system is located, e.g. flat spacetime versus intrinsic curvature? I say this as constraints are easily implicitely assumed and/or subtlety hidden in exam type questions.

Comment: Hi agaminon. In what context? Are they truly constraints and not just solutions to EOMs?

Comment: @StudyStudy It's understood this is in flat spacetime.

Comment: @Qmechanic It's one of the questions in a problem within an analytical mechanics course. I'm asking because a further question mentions "equations of motion", in plural, but if there is only one generalized coordinate there should only be one equation of motion. I'm thinking the plural might be to not tip off the fact that there are two constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those are the Helix equations

$$x=b\cos(\varphi)\\
y=b\sin(\varphi)\\
z=a\varphi$$
the generalized coordinate is $~\varphi~$ thus
you need two constraint equations

$$x^2+y^2=b^2\tag 1$$
$~\text{with} \quad\varphi=\arctan(y/x)\quad\Rightarrow$
$$z=a\,\arctan(y/x)\tag 2$$

if your generalized coordinate is y,  you obtain

$$x(y)=\sqrt{b^2-y^2}\\
z(y)=a\,\arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{b^2-y^2}}\right)$$

the position vector to the mass is then

$$\vec R=\begin{bmatrix}
 x(y) \\
  y \\
  z(y) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this problem in the following way.

We are talking about a particle in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The space it exists in has a dimension of **3**.

But the particle rides on a path (helix) that only takes **1** quantity to fully describe its position.

This leaves **2** constraints needed to complete the space.

---

The basis vectors for constraint forces, must be chosen such that they have a zero inner-product with the motion direction. This is because constraint forces do no work, and hence have zero power

$$ \boldsymbol{F} \cdot \boldsymbol{v} = 0 $$

For example, the velocity vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ is parallel to a direction vector $\mathbf{S}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} - \sin(2\pi t) \\ \cos(2\pi t) \\  \lambda \end{bmatrix}$ which spans one column of $\mathbb{R}^3$ space.

The constraint force vector $\boldsymbol{F}$ is a linear combination of two directions $\mathbf{C}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(2\pi t) & \lambda \sin(2\pi t)  \\ \sin(2\pi t) & \lambda \cos(2\pi t) \\ 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$, both if which must be perpendicular to $\mathbf{S}(t)$ above. This spans the remaining two columns of $\mathbb{R}^3$ space.

$$ \mathbf{S}(t) \cdot \mathbf{C}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

You can prove the combined space has rank 3 and spans the entire space

$$ \mathrm{rank}( \left[ \begin{array}{c|cc} - \sin(2\pi t) & \cos(2\pi t) & \lambda \sin(2\pi t) \\ \cos(2\pi t) & \sin(2\pi t) & \lambda \cos(2\pi t) \\  \lambda & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]) = 3$$